# In-app browser won't load page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, hybrid-mobile-app, inappbrowser

I've recently tried creating an in-app browser function on my app. The function works except it won't load the page. I've created an array in the JavaScript containing the url's and then I have created an ng-repeat to populate the list. Each content in the list needs to take the user to a different page. Could someone please tell me where im going wrong?

**My array:**

```
.factory('UsefulData', function($http){

  var useful = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Services",
      "img": "img/useful/services.png",
      "url": "http://www.amazon.co.uk/",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Plan",
      "img": "img/useful/communications.png",
      "url": "http://www.bbc.com/sport/0/",
    }
  ];

  return {
    all: function() {
      return useful;
    },
    get: function(usefulId) {
      // Simple index lookup
      return useful[usefulId];
    }
  }
```

**My list:**

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="data in useful" type="item-text-wrap" onclick="window.open('{{data.url}}', '_blank', 'location=yes')">
    <img class="imgSize" ng-src="{{data.img}}">
      {{data.name}}
    <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**My controller:**

```
angular.module('Mobilisation').controller('UsefulCtrl', function($scope, $state, $http, $rootScope, UsefulData) {

  $scope.useful = UsefulData.all();

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just creating a variable inside a factory does not make a variable available in one of the views.

The regular approach is adding the variables to a [scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) from inside a [controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller).

So you're factory method would return the contents of `useful` like this:

```
.factory('UsefulData', function($http){
  var factory = {};

  factory.useful = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Services",
      "img": "img/useful/services.png",
      "url": "http://www.amazon.co.uk/",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Plan",
      "img": "img/useful/communications.png",
      "url": "http://www.bbc.com/sport/0/",
    }
  ];

  return factory;
}
```

And you're controller would look like this:

```
.controller('UsefulController', function($scope, UsefulData) {
    $scope.useful = UsefulData.useful;
});
```

Now all you need to do is make sure the scope from the contraller is available within the view with `ng-controller="UsefulController"`, and your links should be available.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the controller, please see edited version. Thanks

Comment: Very strange. Is it true that the `ion-list` and `ion-item` are directives? I think you need to add `scope: true` to the directive if you want to access variables from the scope.